# registration form for seller in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, login, register

I want to crate login and registration form for seller (separate form from user registration and login forms) if user click on seller link it will be redirect to seller page where seller can register and login.After  successful login it should redirect to seller's profile or seller's dashboard.

I added on block in that I called persistent/customer/form/register.phtml for registration and /customer/form/login.phtml  for login and call that block into my page.Login page is work perfectly but registration form is not displaying.I am trying this in custom.phtml. How can I solve this .

Comment: Please explain in detail what exactly you are trying to achieve. Throw some code over here...